# Delete original object after mirroring

Tags: mirror, mirror-modifier

I am trying to mirror a bone in Blender so I can compare it to a contralateral bone that is abnormal. I can successfully mirror the bone by applying the mirror modifier, however, the 2 objects are linked so that I cannot delete the original. Is there a way to separate the objects after mirroring them so that I can delete the original? I've seen others asking this type of question but haven't found anything that works yet. thanks

Comment: It's one object after applying the modifier. You have to go to Edit mode, select the original bone and delete there.

Comment: Wait a minute... Do bones have modifiers in Blender?..

Comment: Could you please edit the question and add some screenshots?

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys I guess he's talking of a modeled bone like from a skeleton. That would fit the rest of his description of the issue.

Comment: @danielnucci As Ffeller said, the mirror modifier doesn't create a new object after applying. It creates a new mesh inside the same object. If you have found other questions but didn't find anything that works, maybe you could point us to the other answers and why they are not working? This would save us from suggesting the obvious solutions...